# What can I do to stop my 4 and 6 year old kids from falling out of a bunk bed on a cruise?

Tags: safety, tips-and-tricks, children, cruising, sleeping

I've got a balcony room booking on the Sun Princess. We're travelling for 1 week, and there are bunk beds for my kids.

My kids roll around a lot at night, and they have a 'bar' that restrains them in their current beds. I'm worried that if they were in a bunk bed they might fall out.

My question is: **What can I do to stop my 4 and 6 year old kids from falling out of a bunk bed on a cruise?**

Comment: Did you check how bunks are accessorized on submarines? It might give you some ideas...

Comment: I believe that [Hammocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammock) are the historically preferred way to avoid falling out of bed on a rolling/rocking ship...

Comment: From the pictures I've seen online, these bunks appear to already have a bar that goes perhaps 1/4 or 1/3 the way down the bed. This might not be sufficient for you, though. You could always let them sleep in the lower beds...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An effective way is to roll a towel. Make it into a long cylinder and place it along the outer edge of the bed. For more safety, you can slip it under the sheet with some extra effort. That way it cannot easily be pushed off. You can easily get additional towels for this on the cruise ship if you don't already have enough, so you wont have to pack extra items.

Comment: I have found it beneficial (in 36 years of professional seafaring) and more comfortable to put the towel/blanket under the outer edge of the mattress. This has the effect of curving the mattress up, so the occupant of the bed has to roll up hill to fall out. It is surprisingly cosy :)

Answer (score 7):

Amazon has many [portable bed rails for kids](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=bed+rail) that come in many sizes and shapes (large, small, long, short, etc.) and they're affordable. They are easily installed on almost any bed/bunk with a mattress.

Check the bunk size, order one that fits it. Do not take any risk and ruin the trip.

Answer (score 5):

Speak to the steward when you arrive. It is unlikely to be the first time this problem has arisen, and ships usually have some sort of straps available for passengers who are nervous (reasonably or otherwise) about falling out of bed in a storm. Asking an expert (who can expect a larger tip) is much better than trying to solve it yourself without knowing the details of the cabin, or even asking here.